# Deploy Svelte app to apache2 does not show meta

Tags: apache, deployment, svelte

I have finished my local developemnt of my Svelte powered site and it works fine. In particular, when I brow locally (in `dev` mode and in `npm run preview` after `npm run build`), the page source has the meta/OpenGraph meta:

```
<meta name="description" content="亚非拉短篇小说集, 多人, （不详）, 出版社：中国社会科学出版社, 出版时间：1980-04-01, 版本1.1, , 10190.021, 小说, 文学">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://rsywx.net/books/01460.html">
<!-- HEAD_svelte-1h7w4y4_END -->
<!-- HEAD_svelte-109doem_START -->
<meta property="og:title" content="亚非拉短篇小说集">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://rsywx.net/books/01460.html">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://api.rsywx.com/books/image/01460/多人/亚非拉短篇小说集/600">
```

But when I pull all the files (including the `build` directory, where my Apache2 points to), the same page does not show the metas:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/entry/start.e279fbc2.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/index.8a61f26e.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/singletons.32130f18.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/paths.7b44e4a3.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/control.e7f5239e.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/entry/app.58a6a264.js">
</head>
```

This is really weird to me.

ps: My `src\routes\+layout.ts` is like:

```
export const ssr=true;
```

Comment: SSR works with NodeJS servers only, as I understand it.  Because rendering the page in the server side requires running JavaScript, I don't think you can deploy directly with Apache.  You probably can set Apache up as a reverse proxy, but your server, again, as I understand SSR, has to be NodeJS.